# How to enable PHP redis extension on Travis

Tags: php, continuous-integration, travis-ci, phpredis

I'm running Travis CI for running my tests. I'm using the Trusty container with php v5.6.

Here is my entire .travis.yml file:

```
language: php

dist: trusty

php:
  - '5.4'

before_script:
  - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
  - before_script: echo "extension = redis.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini

sudo: required

install:
  - npm install -g gulp
  - composer install

env:
  - APP_ENV=circleci

script:
  - gulp test
```

The `before_script:` syntax is copied directly from [the travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php#Enabling-preinstalled-PHP-extensions) but my builds fail with a composer error saying:

```
- The requested PHP extension ext-redis * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's redis extension.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that [this documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#enabling-preinstalled-php-extensions) is incorrect! Instead of `before_script:` it needs to be `before_install:`. This seems to work fine:

```
before_install:
  - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
  - before_script: echo "extension = redis.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
```

Comment: do you know a tutorial or could you please explain how you install redis with phpenv?

Comment: I can confirm that this is workng in PHP7.2 Laravel 6.x Xenial dist